# Bash: Troubles with Sed not replacing string, or emptying entire file

Tags: regex, bash, replace

I have a file with an SQL query in it. I'm trying to alter the value one of the WHERE clauses in the query using the result of a previous query.

So basically, I run my first query and store the result in a variable: "LAST".

Then after that, in my bash file, I have this line:

```
sed -i 's/^AND \`id\` \> ([0-9]+)$/AND `id` > $LAST/g' /query_resources/query.sql
```

As you can see, I'm attempting to use regex to find the line in my query file that resembles this...

```
AND `id` > 12345
```

...And replace the string of numbers with whatever I have stored in my variable.

The problems I'm running into is that either that line is not being changed at all, or I have even had the contents of the file - that I'm doing the search and replace on - completely emptied out.

Comment: I believe in most cases `sed` uses _basic_ regular expressions, where `+` is an ordinary character. If your version of `sed` supports extended regular expressions (as GNU `sed` does with the `-r` option), use that, otherwise replace `[0-9]+` with `[0-9]\{1,\}`

Comment: By the way, you need to escape parentheses too: `\(blah\)`, although you don't really need them in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change to double-quotes in order to convert `$LAST` to it's actual value, and you also need to escape the `+` and all the ` signs:

```
sed -i "s/^AND \`id\` > [0-9]\+/AND \`id\` > $LAST/g" /query_resources/query.sql
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much. I had tried the double quotes before, but I guess it still probably didn't work because I hadn't escaped some of those characters.